# WinError 5 Access is denied when trying to include UPX dir in Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, upx

I downloaded the latest release of UPX, extracted it into a folder on C:/UPX. This folder now contains both the .exe, and the extracted folder. Pyinstaller either does not recognise UPX at all, or it gives me:

> 84 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0.dev0
> 84 INFO: Python: 3.7.6 (conda)
> 84 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
>
> ---
>
> Error running 'C:\UPX\upx -V': [WinError 5] Access is denied
>
> ---
>
> Error: Executing command failed!

The code I used was:

```
pyinstaller --upx-dir C:\UPX --add-data img.png --onefile script.py
```

I am running it from Anaconda prompt and as administrator. When the UPX file was in the current directory where my script is, it was not recognising the upx at all.

I am following all the advice given online, but I have a feeling I am downloading/trying to use the wrong UPX file. I download from here: https://github.com/upx/upx/releases/tag/v3.96 the .zip for the upx-3.96 release. Both the .zip and the extracted folders I keep in this C:/UPX folder. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue.

I tried using the previous release https://github.com/upx/upx/releases/tag/v3.95 and this seemed to work.